# How to create a view with multiple reference to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `Users` and `Details`. The `UserId` is the primary key from `Users`.

On the other hand the column `UserId` from `Details` is a reference from the table `Users`.

**Table: Users**

```
UserId    FirstName    Lastname
1         John         Wick
2         Black        Panther
3         Lebron       James
```

**Table: Details**

```
UserId    ManagerId    SupervisorId
1         3            2
2         3            1
3         3            1
```

If I were to execute a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Details on Users.UserId = Details.UserId
```

The results would be:

**Table: Details**

```
UserId    FirstName  LastName ManagerId  SupervisorId
1         John       Wick     3          2
2         Black      Panther  3          1
3         Lebron     James    3          1
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
UserId    FirstName  LastName ManagerId  SupervisorId
1         John       Wick     Lebron     Black
2         Black      Panther  Lebron     John
3         Lebron     James    Lebron     John
```

Basically to use another column from the table of its reference key. How would I do this?

Comment: You might need to create subqueries.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: @GordonLinoff with aliasing, it is requireq to write second join and  nexts

Comment: @PraveenKumar no subqueries needed.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ah thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join a table multiple times. So you can join the Users table to the Details table, and then back to the Users table again. You just have to give the table an alias.

```
select
    u.UserId, u.FirstName, u.LastName,
    m.FirstName as ManageId,
    d.FirstName as SupervisorId
from
    Users u
    inner join Details d
        on (u.UserId=d.UserId)
    inner join Users m -- Manager
        on (m.UserId=d.ManagerId)
    inner join Users s -- Supervisor
        on (s.UserId=d.ManagerId)
```

Answer (score 3):

The ID for supervisor and manager are in users table?  You would join to that same table with an alias multiple times:

```
SELECT Details.*, U1.FirstName AS UserFirstName, U1.LastName AS UserLastName, 
U2.FirstName AS ManagerFirstName, U2.LastName AS ManagerLastName,
U3.FirstName AS SupervisorFirstName, U3.LastName AS SupervisorLastName
FROM Details 
INNER JOIN Users U1 ON U1.UserId = Details.UserId
INNER JOIN Users U2 ON U2.UserID= Details.ManagerID
INNER JOIN Users U3 ON U3.UserID= Details.SupervisorID
```